# Add conditional formatting rule

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Google Sheets has a great interactive way to declaratively define conditional formatting.  Is there a way to program the same declarative model using App Script?

I have a script that generates many spreadsheets.  I set data and data validation rules using the [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) and [DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder) classes.  However, I can't seem to do the same for conditional formatting.  I expected to find a *ConditionalFormattingRule* object or something like that.

**Note:** I know that custom script can be written that listens for an [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/). However, that script would need to be added to *each* of the *generated* spreadsheets. Also, non-declarative rules like that would not appear in the [conditional formatting sidebar](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en).

I'm simply trying to apply a red background to cells that have no value.

Is this just not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the latest [Sheets api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) you can programmatically add a conditional format rule.

To add a rule that sets the background to red for all empty cells in a sheet you can do this:

```js
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MySheet');

  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1, numRows, numCols);
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenCellEmpty()
      .setBackground("red")
      .setRanges([range])
      .build();        
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

The SpreadsheetApp [newConditionalFormatRule()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newconditionalformatrule) method returns a conditional format rule *builder*, that is used to build a conditional format rule.

You could run this code on each new spreadsheet you create.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that you will have to use a workaround in this case, if appropriate for your circumstance.

You would have to create a template sheet that had cells formatted by conditional formatting (manually done by you) in a source spreadsheet.

Then your script will copy this template sheet over to your target spreadsheet, and then use the [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo%28Range,Object%29) method with advanced parameters of {formatOnly:true} to copy the format of one or a range of cells in the template sheet over to your chosen sheet (finally, you can delete this template sheet from the target spreadsheet).  (The copyTo method only copies from one range to another within the same spreadsheet).

Something like this:

```
function transferFormatting() {
  var targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dLv8V5fKmmxRLi5maLIOgrxVGVaqGGOD7STHbEremQs/edit#gid=0');
  var targetSsDisplaySheet = targetSs.getSheets()[0];
  var sourceSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14RxLXktm0wj-lSFrl5Fas9B-smMYhknFt3-dYQbwH3o/edit#gid=933388275');
  var templateSheet = sourceSs.getSheetByName('Template');
  var targetSsFormatTemplateSheet =  templateSheet.copyTo(targetSs);

  targetSsFormatTemplateSheet.getRange("A1").copyTo(targetSsDisplaySheet.getRange("B:D"), {formatOnly:true});
  targetSs.deleteSheet(targetSsFormatTemplateSheet);
}
```

Comment: Looked very promising.  However, the range to range copyTo() consistently fails with "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

Comment: I have put the script to try it out (and it does work for me) into a spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C_hlAX8KTQa33ltANKEalsy18-TDy6c4ArLwBre3yL4/edit#gid=2037749471      Try it out and let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: There's a method to transfer formatting now range.copyFormatToRange(): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyFormatToRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)

I was previously getting the "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again." using the method in the answer.

Comment: @Stephen Brown, from what I've gathered, both the reference sheet and target sheet need to be in the same spreadsheet to use either `.copyFormatToRange()` and `.copyTo()`. Thus, @David Tew's method above.  Also note that doing a `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` (before or after depending on what you are doing) can help with the "server error" when copying over a sheet.

Comment: In trying to apply a specific conditional formatting to 20 different columns using the method described above (in a for loop), one a single conditional formatting rule is created, encompassing the amalgam of all ranges specified.  I had expected a new conditional formatting rule would be created for each column.  Is that expected?

Answer (score 3):

Also available is the [Advanced Sheets Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) to add Conditional Formatting from Google Apps Script.

Be sure to **Enable Advanced Google Services** from your script. Then you can use `Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId)` to add conditional formatting using [Google Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AddConditionalFormatRuleRequest) and  **Advanced Sheets Services**

Navigate through each JSON representation object to piece together the full request:

- AddConditionalFormatRuleRequest

  - ConditionalFormatRule

    - GridRange
    - BooleanRule

      - BooleanCondition

        - ConditionType
      - CellFormat

```js
// Conditionally sets the background of cells to red within range B2:J1000
function setConditionalFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]

  var format_req = {
    "requests": [{
      "addConditionalFormatRule": { 
        "rule": {
          "ranges": [{
            "sheetId": sheet.getSheetId(),
            "startRowIndex": 1,
            "endRowIndex": sheet.getMaxRows(),
            "startColumnIndex": 1,
            "endColumnIndex": 10
            }],
          "booleanRule": {
            "condition": {
              "type": "BLANK"
            },
            "format": {
              "backgroundColor": {
                "red": 1,
                "green": 0,
                "blue": 0,
                "alpha": 1
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "index": 0,
      }
    }],
  "includeSpreadsheetInResponse": false,
  }

  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(JSON.stringify(format_req), ss.getId())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will format alternating rows in your Google Sheets table:

```
    function lastLine() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

      var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();

      return range.filter(String).length;
    }

    function setConditionalFormat() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]

      var myRange = {
        'sheetId': sheet.getSheetId(),
        'startRowIndex': 1,
        'endRowIndex': lastLine(),
        'startColumnIndex': 0,
        'endColumnIndex': 8
      }


      var format_req = {
        'requests': [
          {'addConditionalFormatRule': {
             'index': 0,
               'rule': {
                 'ranges': [ myRange ],
                  'booleanRule': {
                     'format': {'backgroundColor': {'red': 1, 'green': 1, 'blue': 1, 'alpha': 1}},
                      'condition': {
                        'type': 'CUSTOM_FORMULA',
                        'values': [{'userEnteredValue': '=ISEVEN(ROW())'}]
                      },
                  },
               },

             }
          },
          {'addConditionalFormatRule': {
             'index': 0,
               'rule': {
                 'ranges': [ myRange ],
                  'booleanRule': {
                     'format': {'backgroundColor': {'red': 222/255, 'green': 235/255, 'blue': 246/255, 'alpha': 0.7}},
                      'condition': {
                        'type': 'CUSTOM_FORMULA',
                        'values':
                          [{'userEnteredValue': '=ISODD(ROW())'}]
                      },
                  },
               },

             }
          }      
        ],
      'includeSpreadsheetInResponse': false,
      }

      Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(JSON.stringify(format_req), ss.getId())
    }
```

Comment: Background Color in RGBA. 
Max 255 or 1
If your color is 222, you need divid by 255 to get decimal number.