# GAS : How to format all empty cells in a whole sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to format all empty/blank cells in a whole sheet with a white background but I don't find the best method to retrieve a range that can handle all those empty/blank cells. I don't want to create a conditional rule, I'd like to handle it within a script.

What kind of method should I use ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can create a conditional rule with a script.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57372156/3059685 shows how to create such a conditional rule with a script. The conditional rule in that answer sets the background to "red" for all empty cells in a sheet, so can easily be tweaked for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

*All empty/blank cells* alas, as far as I know, there is no such range in SpreadsheetApp. You have to specify some max area. Say, "A1:ZZ". In this case the solution is quite trivial:

```
function set_all_backgrounds() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:ZZ');
  var backgrounds = range.getValues().map(row => 
    row.map(cell => { if (cell === '') return "white" } ));
  range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}
```

Of course if you will try to use column 'AAA' it could not have the white background.

If you mean all empty/blank cell inside data range, you can get the range this way:

```
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
```